# How do i write the result of a Javascript Promise into an object which is outside the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to write the output of `getStatus` into the object `results`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this? I have already tried a few things, e.g. using `push` to fill an array, but that didn't really work either.

Source:

```
const ping = require('ping');

const results = {}; // my empty object

const ips = {
    server1: '8.8.4.4',
    server2: '1.103.1.1',
    server3: '8.8.8.8',
};

const serverStatus = (hosts) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ping.sys.probe(hosts, function (isAlive) {
            const msg = isAlive ? `host ${hosts} is alive` : `host ${hosts} is dead`;
            resolve(msg);
        });
    });
};

const getStatus = (ips) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(ips)) {
        serverStatus(value)
            .then((s) => console.log(s)) // the promise output
            .catch((e) => console.error(e));
    }
};

getStatus(ips);
```

Output:

```
host 8.8.4.4 is alive
host 8.8.8.8 is alive
host 1.103.1.1 is dead
```